# Determine compiler version of compiled Lua

Tags: lua

I have some compiled LuaQ and I need to determine exact version that was used to compile it, any possible way to do this?

Comment: `LuaQ` means Lua 5.1. `Q` is `0x51` in ASCII.

Comment: The version in the header is really the version of the Lua virtual machine specification. The standard distribution has compiler versions with more precision (5.0.2, 5,3.1, etc.).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Compiled scripts have a header at beginning of file.

```
4 bytes - signature ("\x1bLua")
1 byte - version (0x51)
1 byte - format
1 byte - endianness 
5 bytes - sizes of some types
```

So you can get major version from 5th byte. 0x50 is for Lua 5.0.x, 0x51 is for Lua 5.1.x, etc.
Minor version (to differentiate 5.1.3 and 5.1.4 for example) is not present in compiled files.

Comment: Too bad the `file` command in Linux and Mac OS X don't know about Lua versions newer than 5.1.