# I have problem with Luadec, error: bad header in precompiled chunk

Tags: lua, architecture, decompiling, luadec

I have a problem decompiling a .lua file. I'm using luadec but when I try it say:

```
luadec.exe: file.lua: bad header in precompiled chunk
```

or

```
: not a precompiled chunk
```

I read could be problem of the system's architecture so I tried using 32bit and 64bit Windows but still had the same problem.

How can I solve it?

Comment: It might be Lua version mismatch.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff since i didn't compile it, there are some way to know for sure the version of Lua from the compiled file? Thank you

Comment: see this question for finding the version of a compiled lua-> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32968051/determine-compiler-version-of-compiled-lua

Comment: @ValentinoMare - What are the first 5 bytes of the bytecode?